# Remove row in data table with SweetAlert confirmation

Tags: jquery, datatables, sweetalert

I'm trying to remove a row by pressing the delete icon, but I first want a SweetAlert confirmation window.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      //$( 'button[data-target="#delete"' ).click(function() {
      $('##ads-overview tbody').on('click', 'button[data-target="#delete"', function() {
        swal({
          title: "Weet u het zeker?",
          text: "Deze actie is niet meer te herstellen",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
          confirmButtonText: "Ja, ik weet het zeker!",
          cancelButtonText: "Annuleren",
          closeOnConfirm: false,
          closeOnCancel: false
        }, function(isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {
            swal("Verwijderd!", "De advertentie is succesvol verwijderd", "success");,

            function() {
              table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
            }
          }
          } else {
            swal("Geanulleerd", "De advertentie is niet verwijderd", "error");
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6n3zsfd5/

The alert window is not appearing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working version: https://jsfiddle.net/6n3zsfd5/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var table = $('#ads-overview').DataTable();

      $('#ads-overview tbody').on('click', 'button[data-target="#delete"]', function () {
          var btn = this;

          swal({
              title: "Weet u het zeker?",
              text: "Deze actie is niet meer te herstellen",
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
              confirmButtonText: "Ja, ik weet het zeker!",
              cancelButtonText: "Annuleren",
              closeOnConfirm: false,
              closeOnCancel: false
          }, function (isConfirm) {
              if (isConfirm) {
                  swal("Verwijderd!", "De advertentie is succesvol verwijderd", "success");
                  table.row($(btn).parents('tr')).remove().draw(false);
              } else {
                  swal("Geanulleerd", "De advertentie is niet verwijderd", "error");
              }
          });
      });
});
```

There wasn't anything wrong with how you were calling SweetAlert. There were a few syntax errors in your code and problems with how you were setting up the DataTable. (thanks to **Gyrocode.com** for spotting that!)

For the syntax errors, open up your Developer Tools window or Javascript Console to see the errors that are thrown when the page loads. That will lead you right to the offending lines.

---

Specific code fixes:

You need to initialize the DataTable:

```
var table = $('#ads-overview').DataTable();
```

You don't need two hashes at the beginning of this line, but you do need a closing bracket after "delete":

```
$('##ads-overview tbody').on('click', 'button[data-target="#delete"', function(...
...^..............................................................^
```

There was a stray comma at the end of this line:

```
swal("Verwijderd!", "De advertentie is succesvol verwijderd", "success");,
```

This doesn't really make sense:

```
function() {
    table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
}
```

There shouldn't be any need to wrap it in a function; just call the method.

That should get everything all fixed up. The JSFiddle at the top of this answer includes all of these fixes.

Comment: Nate, don't want to steal an answer from you, but you missed certain points. See [this updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6n3zsfd5/4/). The delegated event handler needs to be there for DataTable to function properly. I also added correct code so row could be removed. Otherwise, great answer, +1!

Comment: @Gyrocode.com thanks much! I've never used DataTable so I was guessing. I appreciate the catch. I'll edit the post to add even more explanation. Cheers.